# Convert hdf5 to netcdf and rename dimensions

Tags: hdf5, netcdf, netcdf4

I have a set of HDF5 files that have the following header:

```
netcdf control-A-2017-05-12-090000-g1 {
dimensions:
        phony_dim_0 = 16 ;
        phony_dim_1 = 16 ;
        phony_dim_2 = 200 ;
        phony_dim_3 = 2 ;
        phony_dim_4 = 1 ;
        phony_dim_5 = 4 ;
variables:
        ...
```

Since it's HDF5, the dimensions are created as `phony_dim_x`. In this case, `phony_dim_0` and `phony_dim_1` are the `y` and `x` coordinates, respectively. I would like to rename the dimensions appropriately. Since renaming dimensions in HDF5 is not possible (since they don't technically exist), I need to convert to netcdf first. to do so I use `ncks in.h5 out.nc`.

However, the header info of the converted file is:

```
netcdf control-A-2017-05-12-090500-g1 {
dimensions:
        phony_dim_0 = 16 ;
        phony_dim_1 = 200 ;
        phony_dim_2 = 2 ;
        phony_dim_3 = 1 ;
        phony_dim_4 = 4 ;
variables:
        ...
```

Here's the important part: the two `phony_dim_[0,1]` dimensions have been combined to a single dimension, `phony_dim_0`. I assume this is because they have the same value, and so the netcdf conversion assumes they're the same.

A variable that was listed in the hdf5 file as
`ACCPA(phony_dim_0, phony_dim_1) ;` is now `ACCPA(phony_dim_0, phony_dim_0) ;`, with two identical dimensions.

Thus, I am not able to rename the dimensions individually. If I do `ncrename -d phony_dim_0,y out.nc`, I get `ACCPA(y, y) ;`

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being with `ncks`. Converting the file with `ncks` resulting in repeated dimensions (e.g. `ACCPA(phony_dim_0, phony_dim_0) ;`)

Using `nccopy` instead, the converted netCDF file did not produce repeated dimensions (`ACCPA(phony_dim_0, phony_dim_1) ;`)